# gtk signal for moving a scale(slider)?

Tags: event-handling, slider, signals, gtk2

Simple question:

I've added some scales (sliders) to my window, and I want to call a method when you move the scale.

What is the signal name that I use for gtk_signal_connect?
ie I should be able to write something like:

```
gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(my_scale), "scale_moved", (GtkSignalFunc)my_event, data);
```

or am I missing something here?

And more importantly - how do I find out in the future what the signal names are? for example - I googled 'gtk_signal_connect' but I didn't find a big list of different signals.

Similarly, I didn't find details about related signals in the GtkScale documentation. (Well, in [this](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkScale.html) page, there is a single signal detail, but it relates to changing the displayed value format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GtkScale` inherits from [GtkRange](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkRange.html), and signals are inherited in GTK+. Therefore, you can connect to the [value-changed](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkRange.html#GtkRange-value-changed) signal exposed by `GtkRange`.

You're on the right track to find the signals exposed by a given GTK+ widget: besides the source code itself, the documentation is indeed the canonical resource, but you should also take the base classes into account in your search.

Comment: the name i used was "value_changed" which works. Any idea why they're different?